# Store with multiple words accepted in Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I store a string with multiple words (any of the words selected is accepted). But, I  got an error saying:

> Invalid expression term

What is the correct way to store with multiple words accepted?

```
string correctDeviceSerialId = ["AEVL2020", "AEVL2021", "AEVL2022" ];
string correctUserId = "";                                            
string repeatDeviceSerialId = "";
while (repeatDeviceSerialId != correctDeviceSerialId)
{
    Console.Write("Enter your Device Serial: ");
    repeatDeviceSerialId = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were few mistakes in the code. I've fixed them and added a comment above.

```
// WRONG: string correctDeviceSerialId = ["AEVL2020", "AEVL2021", "AEVL2022" ];
// You should have a string array instead of string
string[] correctDeviceSerialId = { "AEVL2020", "AEVL2021", "AEVL2022" }; 
string correctUserId = "";                           
string repeatDeviceSerialId = "";

// WRONG: while (repeatDeviceSerialId != correctDeviceSerialId)
// You were trying to compare string array of strings.
// If you'd like to just check if the string contains in your correctDeviceSerialId
while (!correctDeviceSerialId.Contains(repeatDeviceSerialId))
{
    Console.Write("Enter your Device Serial: ");
    repeatDeviceSerialId = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

P.S. Also don't forget to add `using System.Linq` to the top of your file

Answer (score 1):

> What is the correct way to store with multiple words accepted?

There is a syntax error in the declaration in your array.

replace

```
string correctDeviceSerialId = ["AEVL2020", "AEVL2021", "AEVL2022" ];
```

with

```
string[] correctDeviceSerialId = { "AEVL2020", "AEVL2021", "AEVL2022" };
```

which is the shortcut for

```
string[] correctDeviceSerialId = new string[] { "AEVL2020", "AEVL2021", "AEVL2022" };
```

Comment: I updated my code sir. But, I got an error saying " Operator != cannot be applied to operands of type string and string[] " on while loop.